# Problem with displaying data in MERN. My list displays all data and should only show the one with the ID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, mern

Im trying to build a mini forum for a school project.

Im trying to achieve, when im clicking on the link which in this case in under "Title: Test Post 1" i want to go the post and only show the data, which had the same id.

The routes are working when you click the link it goes to the id, it just shows all the data.

Im having a issue with data, it is showing all "posts" instead of the post with the matching ID.

[image]

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Post = props => (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.post.post_vote}</td>
        <td>{props.post.post_title}</td>
        <td>{props.post.post_question}</td>
        <td>{props.post.post_name}</td>
        <td>{props.post._id}</td>
    </tr>
)

export default class ThePost extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/posts/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({posts: response.data})
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    postPost() {
        return this.state.posts.map(function(currentPost, i) {
            return <Post post={currentPost} key={i} />;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Question:</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Votes</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Id:</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.postPost() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Link to="/"><button className="btn btn-primary">Back to posts</button></Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My app.js

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/" exact component={PostsList} />
   <Route path="/create" component={CreatePost} />
   <Route path="/posts/:id" component={ThePost} />
   <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditPost} />
</Switch>
```

My backend

```
postRoutes.route('/posts/:id').get(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id
    Post.findById(id, function(err, post) {
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

I think the problem is here, but im not sure.

```
 postPost() {
        return this.state.posts.map(function(currentPost, i) {
            return <Post post={currentPost} key={i} />;
        });
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

get method with http request need to  have id param,

```
   componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({posts: response.data})
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: you can [edit] your answer, instead of writing updates in comments